# react native archive a folder

Tags: react-native, zip, archive

How can I create a .zip file of a folder using React Native? I have tried using `react-native-zip-archive` but every time I encountered this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'zipFolder' of null`
I was using the code provided on the module page

```
const targetPath = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}backup.zip/`
const sourcePath = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}backup/`

zip(sourcePath, targetPath)
.then((path) => {
  console.log(`zip completed at ${path}`)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

Do I need to do anything else besides installing the module?